# Norm for pointwise convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Does there exist a norm on the space of all real-valued functions on the real line (or on an open set? a compact set?) such that convergence in this norm is equivalent to pointwise convergence?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

No. First note that if $X$ is any set, the space of all functions $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ with the topology of pointwise convergence is simply the space $\prod_{X} \mathbb{R}$ with the product topology. It is well-known that this space is metrizable if and only if $X$ is at most countable, see e.g. J. Dugundji, *Topology*, IX.7.1, p.189. However, if $X$ is countably infinite, then it is an easy exercise to show that there is no norm inducing the topology of pointwise convergence (see e.g. Rudin, *Functional analysis*, Theorem 1.39, p.28, and also Exercise 7 on p.37).

To sum it all up, the space you're interested in is

- (completely) normable if and only if $X$ is finite;
- (completely) metrizable if and only if $X$ is countable;
- not even metrizable in all other situations.

I leave the fact that the norm and metric can be chosen to be complete as an exercise.

Comment: Hi @Theo: could you give a hint or one line justification for why no norm can exist?  Is it in contradiction with the triangle inequality?  (I haven't done the exercise.)

Comment: @Glen: A basic open set is bounded only in "finitely many directions".

Comment: Doesn't "countably infinite" imply "at most countable"?  Perhaps you meant uncountable?

Comment: @Jesse: For me *countable* means finite or countably infinite, so I said *countably infinite* to exclude the finite case. A finite product certainly is normable, a countably infinite product is metrizable but it isn't normable and finally, an uncountable product is not even metrizable.

Answer (score 5):

The first answer does not reply exactly to the question:
indeed, the topology of the pointwise convergence is not metrizable; however, there could be another (metrizable or not) topology with the same convergent sequences! This phenomen happens with the Schur property of $\ell^1$.

[hardmath's example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/33481/1257) answers completely the question. Interestingly, the following article shows also that there is no metric having the same set of convergent sequences as the pointwise convergent sequences:

http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1951-002-01/S0002-9939-1951-0040647-7/S0002-9939-1951-0040647-7.pdf

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** [Realized the sup-norm doesn't even work for continuous functions.  Revised example.]  An example shows that even for continuous functions on a compact set, pointwise convergence doesn't imply convergence in the sup-norm.  Consider $f_k$ defined as $f_k(1/k) = 1$ and piecewise linearly interpolated to $f_k(0) = f_k(2/k) = f_k(1) = 0$, for $k = 2,3,... $.  Pointwise the sequence ${f_k}$ converges to zero on $[0,1]$, but this is not true obviously for convergence in the sup-norm.

Comment: Thank you, but I think this does not answer my question. I did not restrict my question to continuous functions. I am interested if there is another norm for a larger class of functions, or for a proof that such a norm does not exists.

Comment: @Byron Schmuland:  Right, I realized my mistake after posting.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of Dini's theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem), which says that continuous functions on a compact set converging *monotonically* pointwise must converge uniformly.

Comment: Don't feel bad, I also have a wrong answer (now deleted). When a probabilist hears "pointwise convergence", he usually thinks "almost sure pointwise convergence"!