# How do you get pointwise convergence in the context of normed spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Norm for pointwise convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33476/norm-for-pointwise-convergence)

Let $V=C([0,1],\mathbf{R})$ be the vector space of continuous real-valued functions on $[0,1]$.

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence in $V$. Then $(f_n)$ converges with respect to the max-norm on $V$ if and only if $(f_n)$ is uniformly convergent.

As a consequence, since the limit of a uniformly convergent sequence in continuous, we conclude that $V$ endowed with the max-norm is a Banach space.

Now, on $V$ there is also a notion of *pointwise convergence*. Is there a norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{pc}$ on $V$ such that a sequence $(f_n)$ in $V$ converges with respect to $\Vert \cdot\Vert_{pc}$ if and only if $(f_n)$ is pointwise convergent?

Note that $V$ will not be Banach under this norm.

Comment: That anwers my question. Should have looked around a bit more carefully. So there is no norm on $V$ in which convergence is pointwise convergence.

Comment: No problem, and welcome to Math Stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

No, $V$ it self is too small. Look at $$f_n(x)=\max(1,1/(n\cdot x)),\qquad \qquad n=1,2,\ldots$$ it converges pointwise, but the limit is not in $V$.

Comment: This does not exclude the possibility of norming the topology of pointwise convergence. It only shows that there can't be a complete norm. In [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33476/norm-for-pointwise-convergence) I show that the topology is neither normable nor metrizable.

Comment: Why is an uncountable product not even metrizable? Is this an easy fact?

Comment: @Bana: Show that it is not [first countable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-countable_space).