# Pointwise convergence if and only if  $\|f_n-f\| \to 0$

Tags: functional-analysis

Is there a norm in the C[0,1] space function such that this happens?

$ f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x) $ if and only if $ \|f_n - f\| \rightarrow  0$

Whene $f_n$ is a function sucession, and $ f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x) $ means Pointwise convergence

Comment: A norm on what space of functions?  And is $f_n(n)$ a typo?

Comment: Assuming you mean $f_n(x)$ rather than $f(x)$, this is true by definition, in the sense that $f_n\to f$ in the norm topology induced by $\|\cdot\|$. To make the question meaningful you need to specify the topology in which you want $f_n\to f$.

Comment: "Puntal convergence" is very amusing, and practically a googlewhack to boot. It sure sounds like you mean "pointwise", so I edited it to that.

Comment: @rschwieb  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puntal  so now what is a googlewhack? Meanwhile a punt is a type of boat or a method of kicking a ball. Pointwise also works.

Comment: What properties does your $(f_n)$ have?

Comment: Sorry yes is Pointwise ahah i miss translate, no the $f_n$ doesnt hold any particular properties.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/33476/9464

Comment: @WillJagy Can't tell if your question was rhetorical, so: to the best of my knowledge, a googlewhack is managing to get only a single hit with a one or two word search phrase in google. When I tried "puntal convergence" I only got two hits, both here.

Comment: @rschwieb, that makes sense. By itself "puntal" turned up a few things, but when I looked up googlewhack it did say something about two-word combinations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

Suppose there were such a norm; call it $\|\cdot\|$.  For each $n$, let $f_n$ be any nonzero continuous function supported in $(0,1/n)$.  Since $f_n$ is not the zero function, we must have $\|f_n\| > 0$.  So if we let $g_n = \frac{1}{\|f_n\|} f_n$, then we have $\|g_n\| = 1$ for all $n$; in particular, $g_n$ does not converge to zero in the norm $\|\cdot\|$.  But $g_n$ is a continuous function supported in $(0,1/n)$, so $g_n(x) \to 0$ pointwise.  This is a contradiction.

Comment: thanks I was looking for that it is perfect.