# Pointwise convergence and uniform

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, convergence-divergence

There is a norm $\Vert .\Vert$ in the space $C([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ such that

convergence pointwise  implies convergence in norm $\Vert .\Vert$ ?

I think not because if there would be the natural candidate standard $C([a,b],\mathbb{R})$

any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: The answer is no. This is a duplicate see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33476/norm-for-pointwise-convergence

Comment: @OmranKouba This question asks for a norm weaker than pointwise convergence, the other one for equivalence.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Yes, you are right, I think, I already found a distance, based on a previous post: $d(f,g)=\int_a^b\frac{\vert f-g\vert }{1+\vert f-g\vert}$.

Comment: Distance, but not a norm, @OmranKouba. I suspect there is no norm weaker than pointwise convergence, but I don't see how to prove it.

Comment: By "convergence pointwise implies convergence in norm", do you mean general convergence (of filters/nets), or only convergence of sequences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such norm. In fact, for every norm on $C^\infty([0, 1])$ there is a
sequence of smooth functions that converges pointwise but not in the norm.

Let $\Psi$ be a [bump function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) on $\mathbb{R}$ with support $[0,1]$ 
and define $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ by $f_n(x) = \Psi(nx)$.
Although $f_n$ is never identically zero, it is easy to verify that for every $x$ the sequence $\{ f_n(x) \}$ is eventually
zero, so $f_n \to 0$ pointwise.

If we fix a norm, we can define $g_n = nf_n/\|f_n\|$. Since $g_n$ is zero 
wherever $f_n$ is, we also have $g_n \to 0$ pointwise. On the other hand, 
$\|g_n\| = n$ is unbounded, so $\{g_n\}$ is not even a Cauchy sequence in the norm.